# is there have any quick tricks to transfer the pySpark code to SQL query?

Tags: python, sql, pyspark

Is there have any quick tricks to transfer the pySpark code to sql query? thanks.

For example:
pySpark code:

```py
df.filter( (~F.col('date').isNull()) | (F.col('date') != '')).select('acct_nbr')
```

SQL:

```sql
SELECT acct_nbt FROM table WHERE date IS NOT NULL OR date != ''
```

Comment: `WHERE date IS NOT NULL OR date != ''` will return all non-null values, including `''`. I'd guess you instead want `WHERE date != ''` - which will give you non-null values, excluding `''`.

Comment: However, `''` isn't a valid date value. Which data type is used?

Comment: And don't forget to add a tag for the dbms you're using.

Comment: thanks, for the date, it save as string

Comment: Use a proper date data type for date values.